# How to group by all columns instead of individually writing each one?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am writing a query that uses the max function for example:

```
Select *,
Max(date)
From table
Group by 1,2,3 -- etc.
```

Instead of writing out all the columns (there are many) I want to just say group by all the columns in that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select 
  any_value((select as struct * except(date) from unnest([t]))).*, 
  max(date) as max_date
from your_table t
group by format('%t', (select as struct * except(date) from unnest([t])))
```